# How to do heat sink calculation, when junction to case thermal resistance is not provided

Tags: thermal, heatsink

I am not very knowledgeable, so please bear with me.

For heat sink calculation, you need the junction-to-case thermal resistance of the chip, then the case-to-ambient thermal resistance of the heat sink. Why are there datasheets that don't contain the junction-to-case thermal resistance? One example is this [LTC1732-8.4](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/17328f.pdf):

[image: package image with thermal values from LTC1732-8.4 datasheet]

How can you do heat sink calculation without the junction-to-case thermal resistance? Since only the junction-to-ambient resistance is provided, does that mean this chip package doesn't support a heat sink?

The formula I know for heat sink calculation is:

$$T_j=T_a+P_w(\theta_{JC}+\theta_{CA})$$

where \$T_j\$ is the junction temperature, \$T_a\$ is the ambient temperature, \$\theta_{JC}\$ is the junction-to-case resistance of the chip, and \$\theta_{CA}\$ is the heat sink case-to-ambient resistance.

Comment: Is this a specific or general question? LTC1832 draws a couple mA, you'd be hard pressed to get it self-heated any at all.

Comment: Yeah, "Input Supply Current: 3 mA" _maximum_.

Comment: packages without exterior exposed metal surfaces aren't designed to take heatsinks, usually out of a lack of need or an internal bottleneck that runs out of margin long before case temp is problematic. Sometimes tacking on a heatsink can result in somewhat better operation (chip amps, RAM, LEDs, motor controllers, PIs, etc) but these are more subjective improvements than design requirements with engineering specs.

Comment: @Tim Williams general question.

Comment: @dandavis so, is it safe to assume then that if not \$\theta_{JC}\$ is provided, then the chip is not meant to be used with a heat sink?

Comment: The data sheet specifies a θJA value.  You can think of this as being θJC+θCA.

Comment: As pipe says, input current is 3mA *maximum*, so why do you think it needs a heatsink?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat My question was general. I just provided an example, but now it makes sense why it doesn't need a heat sink.

Comment: What happened to the answer that linked to the, package drawing I think it was? That's a good enough answer for the general case, in lieu of actual data -- but, any device you actually want to use at power, will have this rating in the datasheet proper (and if it doesn't, you don't want to use it at power!!). Unrelated: nice typo, I got the part number wrong in my previous comment, a number which doesn't exist, and said comment is the top result for searching it, haha

Comment: You picked a poor example, but there are others which may be more relevant that have a similar issue eg. https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX1507.pdf

Comment: How do you propose to attach a heatsink in any useful manner to an MSOP device, anyway?

Comment: Thermally conductive adhesive is one way.